# Laravel 5.3 and Parsley remote validation

Tags: json, laravel, parsley

i tryed to remote validate the email and username for a registration form with parsley. I get allways the message:

```
public/checkUserName?username=tester 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

So here is my code:

Input:

```
<input data-parsley-remote="{{ route('checkUserName') }}"  data-parsley-remote-message="Der Username ist bereits vergeben!" data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "POST", "dataType": "jsonp", "data": {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, "UserName": "username" } }'
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/checkUserName', [
   'uses' => 'UserController@checkUserName',
   'as' => 'checkUserName'
]);
```

UserController:

```
public function checkUserName(Request $request)
{        
    if(user::where('UserName','=',$request->input('UserName'))->exists()){
           return response::json('exists', 404);
        }else{
           return response::json('not exists', 200);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `405 (Method Not Allowed)` is thrown by `Laravel` because request method `GET` is not allowed to handle the route registered for `POST`.

First of all, I'm not familiar with `Parsley` but after observing your code, what I've found is that, you have setup the `parsley` to send `AJAX` request using `POST` method but the data type is set to `jsonp`.

```
// Extracted from the question
data-parsley-remote-options='{
    "type": "POST",
    "dataType": "jsonp",
    "data": {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, "UserName": "username" }
}'
```

In this case, `jsonp` is not possible using `POST`  method because it sends a `GET` request (using a script tag...) and hence, your route is not found because you've registered the route as `POST`.

So, it's happening because of inappropriate data type (`jsonp`) with the request method `POST`. I'm sure that, the `Parsely` is sending a `GET` request instead of `POST` request because of `dataType:jsonp`.

So, you can check the `network tab` in your browser inspector to find out the request method that is being sent and you should either register the route with `Route::get()` or change the `dataType` to something else, could be `json` but you should check the `Parsely` documentation for available data types.